# How to save an included library in C win32 Console application EXE file

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, exe

I started programming in C and I have **Visual Studio 2012.**

I Write my program in Win32 ConsoleApplication and when I look in the Debug in my project there is an EXE file, and it work, but when i try to take it and run it from other computer that not runs Visual Studio it not working.

what i can do for it to work?

Thanks, Tomas.

Comment: you need to have the framework installed

Comment: Change the build configuration "Debug to Release". Should work.

Comment: You have to bundle the C runtime with your application. There are [merge modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235290%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) available for you to include in your installation package.

Answer (score 0):

go to the project properties and then: C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library and then select the  MT or MTD option depending in which configuration  you are (for release MT and debug MTD)

Answer (score 0):

The standard C functions like `printf`, `fopen` and `strlen` are delivered by the compiler vendor in a precompiled library and DLL. The default setting in projects is to not link all the standard functions directly into your program but keep them in an extra DLL and let your compiled program just use that DLL. On your machine with Visual Studio that DLL is present. On your other machine that DLL is not present.

There are two ways to solve that:

1. Look at the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist` and copy the DLLs you need to the target machine.
2. You can go the project settings "C/C++"/"Code Generation" and change the setting "Runtime Library" to a value without "DLL" in its name (/MT and /MTD). Then the compiler directly links all the standard C functions into your program and you can just copy your program to the other machine.

The reason Microsoft prefers the DLL is that with the DLL you can have multiple small programs in a folder each using the same DLL. If linking statically you end up with multiple bigger programs where each program has built in the same functions.